# How can I return null if the data doesn't exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

how can I use something like `if(!testimonials) return null`for all the data that I pass. it just shows empty array for now. I don't know where to use "if-else" rule.

aboutus.tsx

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }: any) => {
  
  const query = `{
  'stats': *[ _type == "stats"] {
           _id,
        title,
        stat,
        icon
  },
  'testimonials': *[ _type == "testimonials"] {
    _id,
        description,
        author,
        job,
  },
  'clients': *[ _type == "clients"] {
    _id,
        client,
        mainImage,
  },
}`;
  const props = await sanityClient.fetch(query);

  return { props: { 
     testimonials: props.testimonials,
     clients: props.clients,
     stats: props.stats,
   } 
  }; 
  
};

const aboutus = ({ testimonials, clients , stats}: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <AboutComponent
        testimonials={testimonials}
        clients={clients}
        stats={stats}
      />
    </>
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), if the testimonials attribute can be null:

```js
<AboutComponent
        testimonials={!testimonials ? null : testimonials}
        clients={clients}
        stats={stats}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but it looks like you want this component to be dynamic

you can use this

```
<>
  {!!testimonials && (
       <AboutComponent
        testimonials={testimonials}
        clients={clients}
        stats={stats}
      />
  )}
</>
```

this way you transform "testimonials" into boolean and only show  if "testimonials" is true

if you need the ELSE you can do it like this

```
<>
  {testimonials ? (
       <AboutComponent
        testimonials={testimonials}
        clients={clients}
        stats={stats}
      />
  ) : (
    <h1>testimonials does not exist</h1>
  )}
</>
```